# php syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

what I did is, I used a static field in my Database class, to store mysqli object. here is the code :

```
public static $Driver;

public static function Connect()
{
  self::$Driver = new mysqli(self::$Server, self::$DBUsername, self::$DBPassword, self::$DBName);
}
```

later, in another class, I want to use this static field. I tried this :

```
if (Database::Driver->errno != 0) return(false); else return(true);
```

and got this error for that line :

> syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR ...

can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access a static property, you need a `$` after the `::`. The class property `$Driver` is accessed as though it is a variable in scope of class `Database`.

```
 if (Database::$Driver->errno != 0)
 //-----------^^^
```

Without the `$`, it would be parsed as a class constant, and constants, which are primitives, cannot have object properties of their own. Hence the `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`, which means an unexpected `->`.